# RewriteCond and RewriteRule can stop POST?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, post, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess I have these instructions:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Now I'm facing problems to fire any $_POST. No way, neither with php nor html nor ajax nor jquery. No POST values are passed. They simply don't pass to destination file. Can be a problem caused by the above rules and conditions? If yes, how can I get the same result without blocking POST? My need is to externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo and to internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php.

Comment: You usually lose your POST data, if you make an _external redirect_  - because the browser follows that by making a GET request for the new URL next. But I don’t see you doing any external rewriting here to begin with - so not clear, where exactly the issue is supposed to be.

Comment: _“My need is to externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo”_ - you could try and do that with status code `307` - then the browser is supposed to keep the request method, when following the redirect. But it will still have to send all the data again - so if you just uploaded a 50MB video, for example, the browser will have to send that whole 50MB again.

Comment: Redirecting POST request is not a good idea in general. And how _necessary_ would it actually be? How many places you are _not_ in control of, make POST requests to your site? In the places you _do_ control, you should change the target URL in the code to begin with.

Comment: Believe me, lost hours looking for a reason why POST doesn't pass. Made all tries with php, js, ajax, jquery, html. Nope: all the POST values simply don't pass. So I'm looking at .htaccess and wondering if the above rules can be the guilty.

Comment: My need for those rules is to have SEO and SEF url, hiding extensions

Comment: Search engine bots don’t usually make POST requests to begin with, so I don’t see what relevance in terms of SEO this should have here, if you made an exception from this for that request method. Plus, you need to modify your links anyway - leaving them pointing at `/foo.php`, and then redirecting that to `/foo` when requested, would not be much “SEO” in the first place. On the contrary, you’d be adding an external redirect, which slows things down, which for example Google will likely even rather _punish_ you for these days.

Answer (score 1):

your `.htaccess` should be like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

and it will work 
above code only remove file extension but if you want to force redirection 
then your `.htaccess` should be like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Tried, but sadly still POST calls don't pass any value.

Comment: I also would need to hide .php extensions in case any code somewhere in the pages address to a .php file

Comment: above code is working or not? I mean its passing post value or  not because i tested it and its working http://dodiyavijay.com/stack/

Comment: then you have another problem I checked with my test environment and its working   dodiyavijay.com/stack

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot a line of code but now it's working. POST pass values. But since your code only address foo to foo.php but doesn't show in the url foo.php as foo, now the matter is: how can I hide any .php extension without losing POST capability?

Comment: ok now you need to force redirection 301 foo.php to for wait a min i will giving you

Comment: ```RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

Comment: i update the answer  please try second code and delete first one if its work for you then make this answer as solution thanks

Comment: Ok it works. But I had to delete your `RewriteBase / ` since it was giving error 500, and using the rest of the code without it. I mean this code works: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L] –`

Comment: if its work for you then make this answer as a solution thanks

Comment: Yes remove `RewriteBase /` . Thank you dodiya vijay

Comment: NO, unliky I have to say that your code did non solve. While html post is fired, the .htaccess rules and conditions still bock the javascript (jQuery) post method. So, any Idea of how to work around that?

Comment: you need to copy all 4 lines and then you need to replace .php to .html

Comment: I have these rules in place: `RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L] –` They allow html post, but for some reason they block ajax/jquery post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212321/discussion-between-dodiya-vijay-and-gab).